# Visual Studio Windows application not working on another computer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2015

[Source explorer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaKIi.png)I have created a small windows application using visual studio and crystal report. I created the setup file also. when trying to install the application on my computer and is working perfectly. Tried installation on another computer it seems nothing happening after clicking the application.There is no problem in installing but launching the app not showing anything.

Comment: Did you installed crystal report in another machine ? Did you checked the event logs?

Comment: Application: Report 2.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException at Report_2.rptform..ctor() at Report_2.Program.Main() 

When I checked event log I'm getting this error message.

Comment: Faulting application name: SALES APP.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x568111c5
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16864, time stamp: 0x531d34d8
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000047b8c
Faulting process id: 0x12fc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1415dac223e83
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\SalesReport\Sales Report\SALES APP.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: e9df7b00-ad50-11e5-be74-40a8f04dbddc
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Comment: Did you have the same version of framework as like in your system? Are you trying to access any files in the Report_2.Progam.Main()?

Comment: Fixed the issue, the application was not launching since the crystal report run time was not present. unknowingly I installed crystal report viewer instead of run time. Thank you Venkatesh

Comment: Good to know that you have fixed the issue.